# Convert Apache Proxypass to Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm finding difficult to understand how to rewrite these apache ProxyPass directives for Nginx:

```
ProxyPass /api/socket ws://localhost:8082/api/socket
ProxyPassReverse /api/socket ws://localhost:8082/api/socket

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
```

So fa I have tried with:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_redirect http://mydomain:8082/ https://mydomain/alias/;
proxy_redirect ws://mydomain:8082/api/socket ws://mydomain/alias/api/socket;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
```

But without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following options

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```